# HTML image 360 is not working on touch UWP

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I am creating a application on Universal Windows Platform  in which I have Some HTML file and the HTML files contain Product 360 view for this I have use WebView to load the HTML files Now here the issue which I am facing is When I am using mouse pointer to rotate the 360 image on the device it is working fine for me but when I am using touch instead of mouse pointer it is not rotating for me Please help me with the issue.

Note: You use the `https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_x4-3d-spin-8634.php` link for example of product 360 view

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }
        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string src = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/HPS_html/index.html";
            this.MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri(src));
        //this.MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_x4-3d-spin-8634.php"));
        }
```

Comment: This also does not work in Edge. Looks like an issue with the WebView itself. I would submit an issue via the Feedback app or MS connect

Comment: @VIVEK The webview control is based on Edge on windows 10. So as Shawn mentioned, it is a feature which is not yet supported. This cannot be controlled just from our code.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Is there any alternative with that I can perform the same task ?

Comment: @VIVEK AFAIK, no alternative way to do this in UWP technology. Webview in UWP is a lightweight component and it's not recommend to use it to do heavy jobs. Maybe you can think about some other js way to show your 3D model, like BabylonJS, although I haven't tested whether it works on a touch screen.